# how can I select only rows that are not within a week of another type of row?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a data table that essentially looks like this:

```
Employee ID   ACTION    Action DATE
1             SIC       12/10/15 
1             CSL       11/10/15
2             SIC       12/10/15 
2             CSL       11/10/15
1             CSL       10/22/15
2             CSL       10/22/15
1             SAC       10/21/15
2             SAC       10/21/15
```

I am trying to select every row with a CSL action that is not within 7 days of an SIC or SAC action row. The output I desire is this:

```
Employee ID   ACTION    Action DATE
    1             CSL       11/10/15 
    2             CSL       11/10/15
```

What I have tried is joining the table to itself like this:

```
Select *
From 
TableName A join TableName B on Keyfield A = Keyfield B
Where 
A.Action = 'CSL' and
B.Action in ('SIC','SAC') and 
A.Action_DT not between B.Action_DT-7 and B.Action_DT+7
```

But, that returns the undesirable 10/22/15 row, I am assuming because it is more than 7 days from the 12/10/15 SIC row.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what is your date format? mm-dd-yy?

Comment: date format on the table is dd-mmm-yyyy

Comment: That isnt the format on the sample data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may rather need an self-antijoin instead of self-innerjoin. Try it like this:

```
select *
from TableName A
where A.action = 'CSL'
    and not exists (
        select 1
        from TableName B
        where B.action in ('SIC','SAC')
            and B.key_field = A.key_field
            and A.action_dt between B.action_dt-7 and B.action_dt+7
    );
```

**Note:** I did not put any effort into replicating your input data, so this query is only hypothetical and may not even work. You can try it anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I just tried this and I returned not results. I added to the where clause to join Table A and Table B like this:
select *
from TableName A
where A.action = 'CSL'
    and not exists (
        select 1
        from TableName B
        where B.action in ('SIC','SAC')
            and A.Emplid=B.Emplid
            and A.action_dt between B.action_dt-7 and B.action_dt+7
    );

That has returned results and after spot checking the first 5 or 6 it seems to be working! Thank You!

Comment: Ah, geez, @Dennis, you're right, I obviously forgot the actual join predicate. Thanks for spotting, answer updated.

Answer (score 2):

Outer join the table to itself matching *unwanted* results, but filter out hits:

```
select A.*
from TableName A
left join TableName B on A.Action != B.Action
  and A.Action_DT between B.Action_DT-7 and B.Action_DT+7
where A.Action = 'CSL'
and B.Action is null
```

A *successful* join means we *don't* want the row - we want the *missed* joins, which have all nulls for the joined columns, which is why a test for null for any joined column in the where clause returns what we want.

Answer (score 2):

Using only a single table scan (no self join):

```
SELECT Employee_ID, Action, Action_Date
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         COUNT( CASE WHEN action IN ( 'SIC', 'SAC' ) THEN 1 END )
           OVER ( ORDER BY Action_Date RANGE BETWEEN 7 PRECEDING AND 7 FOLLOWING )
           AS cnt
  FROM   Table_name t
)
WHERE  Action = 'CSL'
AND    cnt    = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to doing a join is to use an analytic function with a windowing clause - here, I have used the last_value analytic function:

```
with sample_data as (select 1 employee_id, 'SIC' action, to_date('12/10/2015', 'mm/dd/yyyy') action_date from dual union all
                     select 1 employee_id, 'CSL' action, to_date('11/10/2015', 'mm/dd/yyyy') action_date from dual union all
                     select 2 employee_id, 'SIC' action, to_date('12/10/2015', 'mm/dd/yyyy') action_date from dual union all
                     select 2 employee_id, 'CSL' action, to_date('11/10/2015', 'mm/dd/yyyy') action_date from dual union all
                     select 1 employee_id, 'CSL' action, to_date('10/22/2015', 'mm/dd/yyyy') action_date from dual union all
                     select 2 employee_id, 'CSL' action, to_date('10/22/2015', 'mm/dd/yyyy') action_date from dual union all
                     select 1 employee_id, 'SAC' action, to_date('10/21/2015', 'mm/dd/yyyy') action_date from dual union all
                     select 2 employee_id, 'SAC' action, to_date('10/21/2015', 'mm/dd/yyyy') action_date from dual)
select employee_id,
       action,
       action_date
from   (select employee_id,
               action,
               action_date,
               case when action = 'CSL'
                         then last_value(case when action in ('SIC', 'SAC') then 1 end) ignore nulls over (order by action_date
                                                                                                           range between 7 preceding and 7 following)
               end last_val
        from   sample_data)
where  action = 'CSL'
and    last_val is null;

EMPLOYEE_ID ACTION ACTION_DATE
----------- ------ -----------
          1 CSL    11/10/2015 
          2 CSL    11/10/2015
```